# Bridging openvpn server to use another openvpn connection

Tags: iptables, vpn, routing, openvpn

I installed Open VPN Access server for my server. How can I bridge/link two VPN connections - so when user connects to VPN server this server bridges all traffic to another VPN.

USER -> VPN (USA) -> VPN (CANADA)

Ifconfig outputs this from that first server

```
as0t0     Link encap:UNSPEC  HWaddr 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00  
          inet addr:172.27.224.1  P-t-P:172.27.224.1  Mask:255.255.252.0
          UP POINTOPOINT RUNNING NOARP MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:200 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)

as0t1     Link encap:UNSPEC  HWaddr 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00  
          inet addr:172.27.228.1  P-t-P:172.27.228.1  Mask:255.255.252.0
          UP POINTOPOINT RUNNING NOARP MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:200 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)

as0t2     Link encap:UNSPEC  HWaddr 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00  
          inet addr:172.27.232.1  P-t-P:172.27.232.1  Mask:255.255.252.0
          UP POINTOPOINT RUNNING NOARP MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:5156 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:5046 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:200 
          RX bytes:1043681 (1.0 MB)  TX bytes:2859456 (2.8 MB)

as0t3     Link encap:UNSPEC  HWaddr 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00  
          inet addr:172.27.236.1  P-t-P:172.27.236.1  Mask:255.255.252.0
          UP POINTOPOINT RUNNING NOARP MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:200 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:1057 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:1057 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:754492 (754.4 KB)  TX bytes:754492 (754.4 KB)

tun0      Link encap:UNSPEC  HWaddr 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00  
          inet addr:10.4.83.109  P-t-P:10.4.83.109  Mask:255.255.0.0
          UP POINTOPOINT RUNNING NOARP MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:5 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:5 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:100 
          RX bytes:705 (705.0 B)  TX bytes:289 (289.0 B)

venet0    Link encap:UNSPEC  HWaddr 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00  
          inet addr:127.0.0.2  P-t-P:127.0.0.2  Bcast:0.0.0.0  Mask:255.255.255.255
          inet6 addr: 2a02:xxxx:xxxx:5485::1/128 Scope:Global
          UP BROADCAST POINTOPOINT RUNNING NOARP  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:84744 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:64356 errors:0 dropped:7 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:107299933 (107.2 MB)  TX bytes:9611579 (9.6 MB)

venet0:0  Link encap:UNSPEC  HWaddr 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00  
          inet addr:XXXX  P-t-P:XXXX  Bcast:XXXX  Mask:255.255.255.255
          UP BROADCAST POINTOPOINT RUNNING NOARP  MTU:1500  Metric:1
```

So how to configure iptable or openvps conf? I want that port 80 is still listenable in VPN server 1.

Comment: How is bridging set up on the server? You don't need to set up IPTables here.

Comment: I lost that username so can't answer. But I mean just routing these two VPN's, but how to do it? Bridge was wrong term. So when user connects to VPN1 that routes everything to VPN2. So I want openvpn to use client instance (tun0)